# How to capture data entered into table row component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am out building a timesheet app. The index.js file is the one that renders the wholesome table. The rendered table constitutes of the HeaderRow and TableRow components. HeaderRow is the parent component. TableRow(s) is/are the child component(s) rendered within HeaderRow. The code pasted below works. But I am not able to figure out a way to capture data entered into the TableRow components.

I tried this thing:
- Put an onchange event handler in the  tags of TableRow to capture the event and pass it on to the index.js file via props, so that the state in index.js is modified, and that triggers a render. This doesn't work.

I found a useful article on how to build a data table, but this approach is entirely different from mine - https://www.taniarascia.com/content-editable-elements-in-javascript-react/

If nothing works, I might have to resort to this method as suggested in this article.

```
index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import HeaderRow from "./headerrow";
import TableRow from "./tablerow";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { noOfRows: [], event: null };
this.addRow = this.addRow.bind(this);
this.deleteRow = this.deleteRow.bind(this);
this.change = this.change.bind(this);
}
change(e) {
this.setState({ event: e.target.tdi });
console.log(this.state);
}
addRow() {
let arr = [...this.state.noOfRows];
if (arr.length === 0) {
arr.push(1);
} else {
let arrLastItem = arr[arr.length - 1];
arr.push(arrLastItem + 1);
}

this.setState({
noOfRows: arr
});
console.log(arr);
}

deleteRow(event) {
let arr = [...this.state.noOfRows];
let id = event.target.parentNode.id;
let ix = parseInt(id, 10);
let iz = arr.indexOf(ix);
arr.splice(iz, 1);
this.setState({ noOfRows: arr });
}
render() {
let children = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.state.noOfRows.length; i++) {
children.push(
<TableRow
id={this.state.noOfRows[i]}
delete={this.deleteRow}
change={this.change}
/>
);
}
return <HeaderRow click={this.addRow}>{children}</HeaderRow>;
}
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);


headerrow.js
import React from "react";

import "./styles.css"; 

export default function HeaderRow(props) {
function handler() {
props.click();
}

return (
<table>
<tr>
<th>Feature</th>
<th>Phase</th>
<th>Comments</th>
<th>Monday</th>
<th>Tuesday</th>
<th>Wednesday</th>
<th>Thursday</th>
<th>Friday</th>
<th>Saturday</th>
<th>Sunday</th>
<th onClick={handler}>+</th>
</tr>

{props.children}
</table>
);
}

tablerow.js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
export default function TableRow(props) {
function del(e) {
props.delete(e);
}
function change(e) {
props.change(e);
}
return (
<tr id={props.id}>
<td tdi={props.id} onChange={change} contentEditable="true" />
<td tdi={props.id} onChange={change} contentEditable="true" />
<td tdi={props.id} onChange={change} contentEditable="true" />
<td tdi={props.id} onChange={change} contentEditable="true" />
<td tdi={props.id} onChange={change} contentEditable="true" />
<td tdi={props.id} onChange={change} contentEditable="true" />
<td tdi={props.id} onChange={change} contentEditable="true" />
<td tdi={props.id} onChange={change} contentEditable="true" />
<td tdi={props.id} onChange={change} contentEditable="true" />
<td tdi={props.id} onChange={change} contentEditable="true" />
<td onClick={del}>-</td>
</tr>
);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this using onKeyUp and e.target.textContent

in App

```
  change(e) {
    this.setState({ event: e.target.textContent });
    console.log(this.state);
  }
```

in tablerow.js

```
export default function TableRow(props) {
  function del(e) {
    props.delete(e);
  }
  function change(e) {
    props.change(e);
  }
  return (
      <tr id={props.id}>
        <td tdi={props.id} onKeyUp={change} contentEditable="true" />
        <td tdi={props.id} onKeyUp={change} contentEditable="true" />
        <td tdi={props.id} onKeyUp={change} contentEditable="true" />
        <td tdi={props.id} onKeyUp={change} contentEditable="true" />
        <td tdi={props.id} onKeyUp={change} contentEditable="true" />
        <td tdi={props.id} onKeyUp={change} contentEditable="true" />
        <td tdi={props.id} onKeyUp={change} contentEditable="true" />
        <td tdi={props.id} onKeyUp={change} contentEditable="true" />
        <td tdi={props.id} onKeyUp={change} contentEditable="true" />
        <td tdi={props.id} onKeyUp={change} contentEditable="true" />
        <td onClick={del}>-</td>
      </tr>
    );
}
```

**Note:** now getting the data what you enter in the current cell. not sure what is requirement here. based on that you can update the state.

Comment: Very good answer Muthu. It works. I plan to capture the entries, validate it and post it to a database.